# Issues with ajaxSubmit and serialize

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, submit

I'm having issues posting textarea contents to my database using ajax. I've tried to use both the jquery.form.js plugin by malsap, as well as good ole fashon ajax, and cannot get either to post the values out my textareas. Heres my code:

HTML:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.form.js"></script> 
    <form id="defaultemail-ebook-form">
        <label for="defaultemail-ebook">Email with ebook:</label><br>
        <textarea id="defaultemail-ebook" name="defaultemail-ebook"></textarea>
        <br>
        <div id="defaultemail-ebook-submit-div">
            <input type="button" id="defaultemail-ebook-submit" value="Set Email">
        </div>
    </form>
```

defaultemails.php

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


$defaultemailebook = $_REQUEST['defaultemail-ebook'];

if (isset($_GET['defaultemail-ebook'])) {
mysql_query("UPDATE default_emails SET email_ebook='". $defaultemailebook ."' WHERE id = '1'");

echo $defaultemailebook;
}

$defaultemailnoebook = $_REQUEST['defaultemail-no-ebook'];

if (isset($_GET['defaultemail-no-ebook'])) {
mysql_query("UPDATE default_emails SET email_no_ebook='". $defaultemailnoebook ."' WHERE id = '1'");

echo $defaultemailnoebook;
}

?>
```

AJAX:

```
$(function() {

$("#defaultemail-ebook-submit").click(function(){
var data = $('#defaultemail-ebook-form').serialize();

$.ajax({
url: "defaultemails.php",
type: "POST",
data: data,
success: function() {                        
  alert("Yay");       
  }
}); 
});
});
```

Using .ajaxSubmit

```
$(function() { 
$( "#defaultemail-no-ebook-submit" ).click(function() {
    $("#defaultemail-no-ebook-form").ajaxSubmit({url: 'defaultemails.php', type: 'post'}).delay(100, function() {
        $("#current-no-ebook-message").text($("#defaultemail-no-ebook").val());
        alert("Email without ebook had been set!");
    });
});
});
```

defaultemails.php will update the existing field text when accessed with a trailing name after it (defaultemails.php?defaultemail-ebook=Here+is+your+ebook), so I don't think its the php file. It seems like for some reason the value of defaultemail-ebook isn't being submitted when I use the ajax call. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax call is using POST. In your php file you are checking if `$_GET['defaultemail-ebook']` is set. Change it to `$_POST['defaultemail-ebook']`.